# Connection string in application settings doesn't work when https is enabled: Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I have a .net core web app that works well in local environment. However, I got this exception when I publish it to Azure Web App:

---

[image]

---

Then I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/09/10/managing-secrets-in-net-core-2-0-apps/) and did the same approach as the image shows:

---

[image]

---

However, it fails once the setting is applied.

---

[image]

---

The difference between the tutorial and my web app is that my one has a SSL certification to enable https connection. Do I need some extra management to make the web app get the connection string under this condition?

---

**EDIT:**

I saw @lolops's post and found there was a right coonection string in kudu environment. So I published it again... and it worked. It's odd and I don't know why the problem has been gone.

What I did specially was only restarting my PC. Could this be a solution? Anyway sorry for troubling.

Comment: How do you access the connection string in your code?

Comment: @MartinBrandl In my code I use user secrets as the tutorial explains.

Comment: So you use `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` instead of `Configuration["DefaultConnection"]`?

Comment: @MartinBrandl Yes I modified `Startup.cs` to use the code.

Comment: okay. Sorry then I don't have any clue right now

Comment: @MartinBrandl I understood, thanks anyway.

Comment: looks like you are no longer getting `ArgumentNullException`? Is it possible that `connectionString` was retrieved correctly and the bug is somewhere else in the code? You can try to isolate the issue by display `connectionString` value as described in the tutorial

Comment: @watashiSHUN The view doesn't seem loaded so I can't try even to show the value of `connectionString` in a view.

Comment: Your Program / Startup should call `AddEnvironmentVariables()` somewhere. Post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try visiting https://YOURPROJECT.scm.azurewebsites.net and find "Environment variables", search for your connection string and compare to the variable you use. It will be prefixed with the type of connection you chose (SQLAzure).